# Django - Dealing With Integrity Error And Showing Error Pop up

Tags: python, django, exception, django-models, data-integrity

I have my model.py file as below. I've created a conjugate primary key `date` & `station`.

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django import forms
# Create your models here.
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import User



# Create your models here.
class ManHour(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('date', 'station'),)

    station_choices = (
       ('KHI','Station1'),
       ('ISB', 'Station2'),
       ('LHE','Station3'),
       )

    station = models.CharField(
        max_length=3,
        choices=station_choices,
    )
    date = models.DateField()
    date_time  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    imports_airside = models.DecimalField(max_digits= 5, decimal_places= 3, default = 0)
    imports_landside = models.DecimalField(max_digits= 5, decimal_places= 3, default = 0)
    exports = models.DecimalField(max_digits= 5, decimal_places= 3, default = 0)
```

**Form.py**

```
from django import forms
from manhourapp.models import ManHour
from datetime import date

class DateInput(forms.DateInput):
    input_type = 'date'

class InputForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ManHour
        fields = ['date','station', 'imports_airside', 'imports_landside', 'exports']
        widgets = {
            'date':forms.widgets.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date', 'max':str(date.today())})
        }
```

**Views.py**

```
def form_page(request):
    context = {}

    try:
        man_hour = ManHour.objects.get(pk=request.GET.get("pk"))
    except ManHour.DoesNotExist:
        man_hour = None

    if man_hour:
        context["Total_Imports"] = man_hour.imports_airside + man_hour.imports_landside


    if man_hour:
        context["Total_Hours"] = man_hour.imports_airside + man_hour.imports_landside + man_hour.exports

    if request.method == 'POST':
        properties_Form = InputForm(request.POST, instance=man_hour)
        if properties_Form.is_valid():
            obj = properties_Form.save()
            return redirect("%s?pk=%s" % (reverse('form'), obj.pk))
    else:   
        context['form']= InputForm(instance=man_hour)
        return render(request, "form.html", context)
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" async></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      

        <form target="upload_frame" action="." method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}<br>
            <input type="text" name="Total_Imports" value="{{ Total_Imports }}" class="form-control" disabled><br>
            <input type="text" name="Total_Hours" value="{{ Total_Hours }}" class="form-control" disabled><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" id="submit">
            <div class="user_panel">
                <a href="/logout">logout</a>
            </div>
        </form>           
    </body>
</html>
```

I am new to Django and I want to understand how can I show a pop up that would tell user that record already exists on this date and station.

I need to understand how can I add an exception handling and show pop up to user?

I've tried to add exception handling using code below but it is not working.

```
try:
    if request.method == 'POST':
        properties_Form = InputForm(request.POST, instance=man_hour)
        if properties_Form.is_valid():
            obj = properties_Form.save()
            return redirect("%s?pk=%s" % (reverse('form'), obj.pk))
except IntegrityError as e:
    error_message = e.__cause__
    print(error_message)
```

Comment: The form should be handling that error itself? The error should have been rendered with  the form... Also it looks like you don't return any response if the form is not valid...

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I replaced `print(error_message)` with `return HttpResponse(error_message)` in exception handling in `views.py` file but I am still getting an error `view pages.views.form_page didn't return an HttpResponse object`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Form` class in Django will perform validation and cleaning for you. It will **not** raise errors but catch them itself so using a try-except does not make much sense as the form itself has caught the error.

Instead you just need to return a response in case `.is_valid()` returns `False`. Furthermore the form itself will render the errors to display it to the user when you render it so you should simply render the same page again:

```py
if request.method == 'POST':
    properties_Form = InputForm(request.POST, instance=man_hour)
    if properties_Form.is_valid():
        obj = properties_Form.save()
        return redirect("%s?pk=%s" % (reverse('form'), obj.pk))
    context['form'] = properties_Form
    return render(request, "form.html", context) # form was not valid so returning a response here
```

If you want to customize the error message that is generated you can do it by setting the `error_messages` attribute on the `Meta` class of the form (See [Considerations regarding model’s error_messages [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#considerations-regarding-model-s-error-messages)):

```
from django.core.exceptions import NON_FIELD_ERRORS


class InputForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ManHour
        fields = ['date','station', 'imports_airside', 'imports_landside', 'exports']
        widgets = {
            'date':forms.widgets.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date', 'max':str(date.today())})
        }
        error_messages = {
            NON_FIELD_ERRORS: {
                'unique_together': "%(model_name)s's %(field_labels)s are not unique.",
            }
        }
```

Comment: Now I am able to see the response. However, I am confused on how this error message got generated? If I need to customize this error message and the way it is represented how can I do that?

Comment: @Lopez the form performs validation and cleaning as I stated previously. Check my edit if you want to see how to customize the error messages.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Can you please provide link or idea on how can I provide user to edit record in case primary key exists?

Comment: @Lopez aren't you already doing that? you pass `instance=man_hour` hence updating the passed instance. Anyway see [Introduction to class-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/class-based-views/intro/) and try using `UpdateView`.

Comment: Thanks I will try that. However, the instance is not being replaced as per the current method.

Comment: @Lopez you seem to be using `request.GET.get("pk")` is the pk even passed in the GET parameters? Furthermore in case of a POST request this doesn't make much sense. You should instead simply add the pk into your url pattern.